# "python -v" output too long

Tags: python

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and I entered `python -v` in the terminal to see if Python was installed. It is indeed installed, but before the line detailing the version I have installed (e.g. `Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)`, there is a large amount of output with lines like:

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
import errno # builtin
```

If I remember correctly, this sort of thing isn't usually output from `python -v`. Also, when I use CTRL + D to exit the interpreter, I get a series of outputs that look like:

```
# cleanup[2] warnings
# clear sys.path_hooks
```

Can someone explain what's going on here, and if something is wrong how I can fix it? Thanks. Also, if this is actually what the output is and my memory is wrong, that would be great! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use uppercase V for the version. the `-v` flag means "verbose", and will show all its import search activity .

Comment: alternately, `--version`, which I find easier to remember

Comment: The verbose thought actually crossed my mind, but I said to myself, "But it's v! v means version!" Yet again, it's something simple I've overlooked. >.< Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The **"-v"** attachment lets you see , what happens when you launch "Python" on console.
         Its like booting up of Linux OS. Similarly when you exit python , it shows you all the operations done internally before Python shuts down. Pretty Cool.

I found a better answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799035/used-python-v-instead-of-python-version-command-to-find-the-version-of-python)